# Data source for MasterCard EMV tag 9F7E - Application Life Cycle Data

Tags: smartcard, apdu, emv, tlv, mastercard

I'm working on a profile for MasterCard EMV cards on M/Chip Select 4 version 1.1a, and I need some help understanding the data elements for the **9F7E (Application Life Cycle Data)** tag value. Unfortunately, the MasterCard manuals do not explain this tag's purpose nor the corresponding data elements very well.

I understand from the manuals that the first byte is for the version number - easy enough. However, the other 47 bytes represent data elements I'm not familiar with, such as "Type Approval ID", "Application Issuer ID", and "Application Code ID."

Are these data values generated during transaction processing, or are they static values residing on the card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M-Chip tag **0x9F7E** "**Application Life Cycle Data**" is **static**, comes from **Issuer**, used at the contact *card profile personalisation*.

"Depending on the possible separation between the loading of the application code and the personalization data on the hardware, only part of the Application Life Cycle Data may be personalized".

For test reason any dummy data could be set in this tag if you have no cases to check the content at the terminal.

Comment: Thanks -- your response is very helpful! Did you find this information in a MasterCard manual?

Comment: Sure it is in Mastercard specifications.

Comment: Search "Issuer Guide to Debit and Credit Parameter Management" for subfields descriptions and M/chip "Card personalization for application Type Approval" for some tag 0x9F7E samples.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, we only need to personalize start 8 byte where first byte tells about master card version ( select or advance) 03 for select , 04 for advance.

In my case, rest 7 byte I got from chip vendor.

Some cards needs full data during personalization of DGI, here need to put dummy data, some cards only need 8 byte of data , rest work is done by card itself.

Hope it helps..